# Calendar repeating alert

Tags: caml

I have a sharepoint calendar which I would like to send out alerts for recurring appointments.
All the appointments are on a monthly basis, e.g. every 3rd of the month.

I have a reminder web part that I can configure using CAML.  Due to the 'unique' way sharepoint configures repeating calendar events I'm going to have to use CAML to calculate the reminder each month.

So I need to know how to write a query that basically works out when if today is the 3rd day of the month. e.g. [Today] = 03/xx/xxxx